# Why react router not rerender component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have router

```
  {
    ...PageItem,
    path: '/page/item/:id',
  },
  {
    ...Page,
    path: '/page',
  },
```

I have first component with data from props. And when I want go to current item I use this and it redirect me to second component and all works:

```
 <Link to={{pathname: "/page/item/" + page.id}}>go to item</Link>
```

But from the second component if I press to browser prev page button or use

```
 <Link to={{pathname: "/page"}}>go to list</Link>
```

all not working. My first component not rerendering (I get props in first component in componentdidmount and it's not calling). First component trying render page with props from second components and give me errors.

Why my props not changing and how to fix this?

ps I use:

```
"react-router-config": "1.0.0-beta.4",
"react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
```

Comment: can u post a little bit more of your router config?

My guess is that you are missing an "exact" in the routes.

Comment: I have exact:true on default page '/'

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately react-router is meant to be used for SPA (Single Page Applications) if you want to use path to acces pages you must use server side rendering, I recommend Next framework which is very easy to use here the link https://nextjs.org
You can also find some good tutorials for react isomorphic rendering on the web.

Comment: I use SSR and in didmount I'm fetch data from server, but componentdidmount not called when page changing